# «Чудесный внук» vs «чудный внук»

Tags: выбор-слов

> Откройте секрет: как воспитать такую **чудесную** внучку?
>
> Откройте секрет: как воспитать такую **чудную** внучку?

Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению один отличается от другого?

В чем разница между «чудесный внук» и «чудный внук»?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, оба варината допустимы. В Нацкорпусе нашлись чудесные и чудные дети/внуки примерно в равных количествах.

Возможно, есть небольшая разница в оттенках смысла. На мой взгляд, "чудесный внук" — это  прекрасный внук, а чудный — тоже прекрасный, но с оттенком удивленного восхищения тем, насколько он прекрасен.

> [ЧУДЕСНЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), -ая, -ое; -сен, -сна, -сно. 
>   1. Являющийся чудом (1 зн.), сверхъестественный, волшебный. Ч-ое исцеление. Ч-ые превращения. Ч. огонь. // Наделённый такой силой; чудотворный. Ч-ая икона. Ч-ая чаша. Родник считали чудесным. 
>   2. Проникнутый фантастикой, полный чудес; удивительный, необычный. Ч-ые сказки. Ч-ые рассказы о тайнах вселенной. 
>   3. =Чудный (2-3 зн.). Погода ч-ая. Ч-ое лицо. Чудесен был её голос. Какой ч. человек! Ч. край. Ч-ая страна. Ч-ые места. Ч-ое время. Ч-ая рыбалка. Ч-ая покупка. <Чудесное, -ого; ср. (1-2 зн.). Вера в ч. Вторгнуться в область чудесного.
>
> [ЧУДНЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20), -ая, -ое; -ден, -дна, -дно. 
>   1. Вызывающий удивление своей необычностью; волшебный. Ч. свет (сказочный). 
>   2. Прекрасный по красоте, прелести. Ч-ая горная природа. 
>   3. Удивительный, необычный. Ч. случай. Ч. дар.